# WPF Datagrid Button commandParameter in code behind

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to build a datagrid with columns and a button in code behind and I want to assign the command parameter of this  button to the value of the "ID" column which is "TDENT_ID". Here's my code
[image]

this line is not working as you can see :

```html
BtnDetail.SetBinding(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding() { Source = dtGrid, Path = "TDENT_ID" });
```

How can I write it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`FrameworkElementFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory?view=net-5.0#remarks):

> "This class is a deprecated way to programmatically create templates, which are subclasses of FrameworkTemplate such as ControlTemplate or DataTemplate; not all of the template functionality is available when you create a template using this class. The recommended way to programmatically create a template is to load XAML from a string or a memory stream using the Load method of the XamlReader class." [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory?view=net-5.0#remarks)

Your `Binding`is wrong. It currently points to the `DataGrid` which does not have a property `TDENT_ID`.

This property is on your data item, which is the `DataContext` of the  column's template.
Therefore, correct `Binding` would be:

```
// Set up a Binding that uses the current DataContext as Binding.Source
BtnDetail.SetBinding(ButtonBase.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding(nameof(myItemType.TDENT_ID)));
```

[Microsoft Docs: Specifying the binding source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0#specifying-the-binding-source)

Try to learn XAML. It makes writing such UI related code much easier, which makes you more productive.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is what i was looking for.